# Flutter animations: showSearch with opencontainer

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

In Flutter's `animations` package, one of the case example of using Container transform animation is

> A search bar into expanded search

The usual way to show expanded search right now is using `showSearch` function, and the only thing I know in modifying the search animation is trough the search delegate.

Is there any way to use `openContainer` with `showSearch`? Or should I create my own search page to open with `openContainer` instead of relying on `showSearch`?

Comment: "Or should I create my own search page to open with openContainer instead of relying on showSearch?" - it seems so

Answer (score 1):

```
Here I found a Solution that may be complex because in our SearchDelegate we can't 
implement animation implicitly.
We can change the package provided by flutter. GoTO 
<Flutter Sdk Path>\packages\flutter\lib\src\material\search.dart(Ex: 
E:\software\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\material\search.dart)
enter code here
Inside  Official Search.dart we can make changes accordingly...

Here what I have done to change the animation Duration and type of Animation itself...

To change the animation DUration: line no 341
  Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 700);//give your
// flexible number

To change the animation : line no 353
return your own animation type default there will be FadeTransition from line No 353-356 you can use SlideTransition, ScaleTransition in the place of FadeTransition
return SlideTransition(        //for slide transition return this instead of Fade 
 //Animation
               position: Tween<Offset>(
               begin: const Offset(0, -0.5),
               end: Offset.zero,
             ).animate(animation),
             child: child,
           );
  // ScaleTransition( //for scale transition uncomment this(ZoomIn and Zoom out)
   //   scale: Tween<double>(
   //               begin: 0.0,
   //               end: 1.0,
   //             ).animate(
   //               CurvedAnimation(
   //                 parent: animation,
   //                 curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
   //               ),
   //             ),
   //             child: child,
   //           );
```

If you want to change the label from Search to your custom Label
provide the label in the class which you have extended with SearchDelegate
inside super() as property searchFieldLabel

```
  To Change the Label :
  class StoreSearch extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  // @override
  // TODO: implement searchFieldLabel
  StoreSearch()
    : super(
        searchFieldLabel: "StoreSearch",//provide your Label here
     );}
```

Comment: Can you share how to open search to show the animation

Comment: Lol, this was smart, is there a way to recover the original file again once we have messed up with the code in it?

Comment: Yes, you can recover using flutter clean and flutter pub get. If not download the flutter again.